# Proof for 2 rak'at Nafl after Zuhr, Maghrib, Isha?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunnah, bidah

In books it mentions that after the Fardh and Sunnah for the above prayers you can optionally pray 2 Rak'at Nafl. Which Hadith says this please?

Comment: Usually the barelvi sect says this. 2 rak'at Nafl after Zuhr, Magrhib(this one has proof though but not limited to just 2) and Isha and sometimes also say after Witr! In fact if you ask them how many rak'at in Zuhr prayer or other ones of the above, they would reply Zuhr is 12 rak'at, i.e. they include the nafl too.

Answer (score 1):

You may find evidences for that in [this search](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%81%D9%90%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D8%AC%D9%8E%D9%86%D9%91%D9%8E%D8%A9%D9%90%20%D8%A3%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%92%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%90%20%D8%B1%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%8D%20%D9%82%D9%8E%D8%A8%D9%92%D9%84%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B8%D9%91%D9%8F%D9%87%D9%92%D8%B1%D9%90%20%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%92%D8%B9%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90%20%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D8%AF%D9%8E%D9%87%D9%8E%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%92%D8%B9%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90%20%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D8%AF%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D9%85%D9%8E%D8%BA%D9%92%D8%B1%D9%90%D8%A8%D9%90%20%D9%88%D9%8E%D8%B1%D9%8E%D9%83%D9%92%D8%B9%D9%8E%D8%AA%D9%8E%D9%8A%D9%92%D9%86%D9%90%20%D8%A8%D9%8E%D8%B9%D9%92%D8%AF%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D8%B9%D9%90%D8%B4%D9%8E%D8%A7%D8%A1%D9%90%20) on sunnah.com

So it is mentioned in almost all known hadith compilations on the authority of at least 5 sahabah. 
For Example in Sahih al-Bukhari:

> I remember ten Rakat of Nawafil from the Prophet, two Rakat before **the Zuhr prayer and two after it**; **two Rakat after Maghrib prayer** in his house, and **two Rakat after 'Isha' prayer** in his house, and two Rakat before the Fajr prayer and at that time nobody would enter the house of the Prophet.
>
> Hafsa told me that the Prophet (ﷺ) used to offer two Rakat after the call maker had made the Adhan and the day had dawned.

Comment: This speaks of Sunnah Ratibah, not Nawafil.

Comment: @Crimson sunnah and nafl are basically the same only later scholars made a difference and the terms sunnah ratibah was not existing in the 2 or even 3 first centuries.

Comment: But what the question is asking about is the additional Nawafil after the ones mentioned in this Hadith. So this still does not address the question. The question asks evidence for example praying nafl after the 2 rak'at Sunnah of Dhuhr, i.e. 2 and 2 in total 4 rak'at after the Fardh of Dhuhr. Similarly, praying 2 rak'at nafl after the 2 rak'at Sunnah of Isha, i.e., 4 rak'at after the Fardh of Isha. And same with Maghrib too.